# Typo in Nyquist's 1928 paper?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, noise

In Nyquist's famous 1928 paper [*Thermal Agitation of Electric Charge in Conductors*](https://wwwusers.ts.infn.it/~milotti/Didattica/Segnali/noise_papers/Nyquist_1928.pdf), equation (8) goes as follows :
$$
E_\nu^2 d\nu = \frac{4R_\nu h d\nu}{e^{h\nu/k_B T}-1}
$$
with

- $\nu$ the frequency of the charges fluctuations of position in the electrical circuit,
- $E_\nu$ the electromotive force,
- $R_\nu$ the resistance of the electrical circuit,
- $T$ the temperature of the resistance
- $h$ & $k_B$ the Planck and Boltzman constants respectively

with the $\nu$ indices indicating a dependence on the frequency.

Should it not rather be
$$
E_\nu^2 d\nu = \frac{4R_\nu h \nu d\nu}{e^{h\nu/k_B T}-1}
$$
(with an additional $\nu$ factor in the numerator)?

If we suppose, as the author suggests, that $h\nu/k_B T \ll 1$, it is possible to expand the exponential as $e^{h\nu/k_B T} \approx 1+h\nu/k_B T$, leaving us with
$$
E_\nu^2 d\nu = 4R_\nu k_B Td\nu$$
which corresponds to equation (4) that shall be retrieved in this limit according to the author.

So should there effectively be a $\nu$ in equation (8) or am I missing something?

Comment: Please define all the symbols in the first equation. This is a very good post and it's best if it's self-contained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it should be as you suggest since he changes the energy per degree of freedom from $k_{\rm B}T$ to

$$
\frac{h\nu}{e^{h\nu/k_{\rm B}T} - 1}\,.
$$

He explicitly states in the text before equation (7).

We can also just use dimensional analysis:
The dimensions of the first equation in the question post are
\begin{align}
\text{Voltage}^2 / \text{Frequency} \cdot \text{Frequency}
&= \text{Resistance} \cdot (\text{Energy} \cdot \text{Time}) \cdot \text{Frequency} \\
\text{Voltage}^2
&= \frac{\text{Voltage}}{\text{Current}} \text{Energy} \\
&= \text{Voltage}^2 \cdot \text{Time}
\end{align}
which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I think too, thank you for taking the time to answer, I'll let the opportunity for other people to express their views before accepting your answer.

Comment: @DanielSank, How do you justify that the units of $E_\nu$ are Voltage/Frequency^{1/2} ? Something more natural to me would have been Voltage/Frequency but then units do match with the original equation of the paper. You must be right though so that units are homogeneous in equation (4) too. Do you have a physical explanation of what is this 1/sqrt(frequency) ?

Comment: @Mary You're asking a *very* common question. Noise has the property that the power increases linearly with the frequency bandwidth. Since noise is $\text{Voltage}^2/\text{Resistance}$, that means that the mean *squared* voltage of noise scales linearly with frequency bandwidth. Therefore, it is completely natural to define a quantity called "voltage noise spectral density" with dimensions $\text{Voltage}^2/\text{Frequency}$. You can then talk about the square root of this thing, which is less physical than the noise spectral density itself, but still often used, i.e. in engineering.

Comment: Aargh, I wish I could edit my previous comment. It should say *"Since **power** is $\text{Voltage}^2/\text{Resistance}$..."*